# kotlin: Дан массив размера N. Найти номера двух ближайших элементов из этого массива

Tags: функции, kotlin, циклы, for, arraylist

Код:

```
var n = 5
var a = IntArray(n){(Math.random()*10).toInt()}

println(a.joinToString())

var k = 0
var k2 = 0

for (i in 0..n-1) {
    if (a[i]<=a[i+1]) {
        k=i
        k2=i+1
    }
}

println("$k $k2")
```

Выдает ошибку

> Array index out of range: 5

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: выдает ошибку Array index out of range: 5 / вроде бы все правильно писал, что не так?

Comment: На последней итерации цикла у вас будет выход за пределы массива, т.е. `if (a[4]<=a[5])`

Comment: На все ваши прошлые вопросы есть ответы, но ни один не [принят](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: а каким образом их принять, я незнаю

Comment: Нажать слева от выбранного ответа на галочку серую, чтобы она стала зеленой, это по ссылке есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле вы обращаетесь к элементам массива с индексами `i` и `i + 1`. Чтобы не выйти за пределы массива, используйте метод [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) вместо оператора `..`:

```kotlin
for (i in 0 until n - 1) {
    ...
}
```

Отличие метода [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) от `..` (или [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html)) в том, что он возвращает диапазон чисел, исключая последнее значение, например:

```kotlin
println((1..4).toList())
// получим [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```kotlin
println((1 until 4).toList())
// получим [1, 2, 3]
```